An intensional system of meaning for predicates? (And related thoughts)
In general, I am interested in a paradigm something like this:
When we have premises, there are rules that can allow us to derive consequences of those premises.
Sometimes, going in the reverse direction seems harder. This has been called “inductive inference”, and is a unifying theme in a lot of the mathematics behind machine learning.
However, what if “going backwards” isn’t actually “harder” (either mathematically or just conceptually), if we just change a needless conceptual bias that our computations are “going backwards”, and instead conceive of a way to think of those “inductive inferences” as “deductive” and “going forwards”, simply because we flipped the origin and the destination?
To be more specific:
On a highly general level, any formal system that models propositions about the world often takes the form of terms + predicates. (Unless I am deeply biased by what I have been exposed to, which is a good question to consider).
What is behind this structure? Terms are usually “things”, and predicates make some kind of assertion about things. However:
Is this a metaphysical phenomenon, or a syntactic one?
Are we saying that in order for a “world” to have any recognizable character at all, we need to distinguish between “things” vs. “properties of things”?
Or are we syntactically saying, “any scrutable concept can be a thing - think of nominalized verbs and nominalized adjectives - and linguists say that semantic concepts exist prior to grammatical categories”.
In the latter case, does that mean that “properties” are just a syntactic way of referring to other things?
If I say “Trinh is married to Ding”, normally, we might say Trinh and Ding are things, and “married to” is a relationship. A relationship is not a thing. It is of some other fundamental category.
If I say “Apples are sweet”, in predicate logic, we have a term Apples, and a predicate “are sweet”. It’s interesting that predicative adjectives would seem to be modeled as unary relation, in logic. Is there something odd about that? It’s like we insisted relationships aren’t things - verbs like “is” and “has” don’t have the concreteness of things like “books” or “the government”. But for unary predicates, or adjectives, it feels like we are associating a thing with some other conceptual thing. Surely “sweet” is something with conceptual structure, like “apple” - it would be weird to pull it out and put it in some other domain.
Do we then need a third “sort”, in our logic - things, relationships, and… qualities?
Maybe. It does invite one to consider a new structure. We can also have special links between “red” as quality (adjective) and “redness” as phenomenon (noun), for example.
Where I really want to go with this is the structure of predicates. I find it deep, unexplored philosophical terrain how functions and relations are, apparently, identified with their set of values. Normally, we would have a conceptual distinction between what ‘is’ means, versus the entire collection of examples of ‘A is B’ as mere examples or instances of the meaning of ‘is’. But in FOL, relations have no other “substance” than their set of values: a binary relation, for example “less than or equal to”, is explicitly defined as a subset of a product of two sets. You can describe properties relations have. But is there some better way to inherently describe what they mean? Can the meaning of relations and verbs and predicates be made intensional, as somehow built compositely from “units of predicative meaning” (things like states, actions, …)
We can bring this back to math, perhaps.
Consider f = x^2.
I think we can axiomatize the squaring function by stating some properties it should fulfill, and then when we look for models of that function, maybe we prove there is only one up to isomorphism.
I think the same thing can happen in the opposite direction: for a given collection of sets, maybe we could realize that they are axiomatizable in a certain way; we treated the values as “the inherent source of what something is”. This is the paradigm of, “If you want to define “the general concept of a dog”, take the collection of all dogs.” Structurally, it seems interpretable as “dogs in general”, hence the concept “dog”.
I am wondering if inductive definitions give us a middle way, but I’m not sure. It’s hard to articulate. Perhaps a good place to start is analyzing further why it feels like it’s missing something to say that any relation can be defined, a priori, by its extension - that instead of understanding what “liking” is, and then very much as a secondary consequence, being able to provide a range of examples of people who like each other, we actually feel a need to go backwards, apparently because we don’t have anything else to work with, so we define “liking” as “that particular thing which all of the following examples have in common”. It also touches on the paradigm of functions as merely being “arbitrary mappings from a domain to a codomain”, versus an older notion of a function as inherently computational, a productive process. There are ways to define addition and multiplication without already pre-assuming the existence of all the known values of those functions.
There’s more to be said, but I have to leave it here for now. But a key idea here is: do we take “terms” as structures with some kind of inherent semantic content, but we only ever taken relations as structural relationships between terms, devoid of their own inherent semantic content? It seems like there is something wrong, there.

It might not matter and in more 60 years, this is the first time I've come across 'intensional' in any context.
Whether or not that matters, to what are the 'And related thoughts' actually related?

You say:

What is behind this structure? Terms are usually “things”, and predicates make some kind of assertion about things. However: Is this a metaphysical phenomenon, or a syntactic one?

It's both. The grammar reflects the organizing principles of thoughts. In English we have nouns, but nouns usually indicate entities. Grammatical predicates on the other hand usually indicate properties and relations. This, of course, echoes the idea that we can have sentences that become assertions, or syntax that becomes semantics. On the one hand, we have the more concrete and public aspect of language, and on the other, we have thought and why LW had to comment on "private language". This is why, strictly speaking, definitions are not concepts, but rather are adjacent to them.
One explanatory inference that emerges from this is the language of thought hypothesis which claims that our thoughts are somehow fundamentally language-like, which should probably taken to mean grammatical and generative. This follows quite naturally from Chomsky's work on universal grammar where he set aside the ad hoc nature of traditional grammars and proposed structures of the mind and brain based on the generative nature of language itself. Both LoT and UG have empirical problems so they tend to be seen more as unrealistic counter-reactions to the excesses of psychological behaviorism and linguistic structuralism under Bloomfield.
One of the chief bugbears in the philosophy of language is how to deal with the syntactic-semantic interface. Traditionally, semantics very much leads into metaphysics, whereas syntax tends to be seen as a the vehicle for meaning-bearers in the same way propositions are seen as the vehicle for truth-bearers. It is not outrageous to see Tarski as the second star in formalization of language with his truth-conditional semantics and work contributing towards mathematical logic. In fact, the scuffle of syntax and semantics reached a fevered pitch between interpretive semanticists and generative semanticists in the 60's and 70's and was called the Linguistic Wars by Harris. (They did have a common opposition to linguistic formalism as a method started by Montague with his take on semantics (SEP)).
Since the 70's a great deal of work and refinement has occurred in
pragmatics, and has shifted meaning from being born by sound or syntax as to being imposed by speakers on the message. Thus, both the metaphysical content of propositions and the semantics assigned to sentences is often seen in terms of an act of applying context appropriately in both explicatures and implicatures. Thus, the meaning of predicates, or any grammar generated in a language, rests partially in convention and partially in inference, or so Sperber and Wilson would advocate in their relevance theory.

@shindemo in a whisper I'm Batman.

Here's another answer to another aspect.
You ask:

[D]o we take “terms” as structures with some kind of inherent semantic content, but we only ever taken relations as structural relationships between terms, devoid of their own inherent semantic content?

Terms if read as noun and nomial phrases are generally associated with entities, and obey the Principle of Compositionality. Therefore, they have morphemic structure, lexemic structure, and phrasal structural (and arguably graphemic structure) in written form. Thus, yes, there are several layers of phonetic and syntactic structure that impact semantics of a phrase. An idiom like "Raining cats and dogs" has a word with four lexemes, seven morphemes, and one conjunction, and the phrase doesn't even have the literal meaning assigned of the parts.
Relations are tougher to characterize in linguistics because they are not always explicitly rendered with operators.  Of course we have conjunctions and prepositions, but appositives, at least phonetically speaking rely on sequence. This leads to ways of conceptualizing grammars, as dependency sorts and constituent sorts. Sometimes, in fact, relations are indicated with grammatical particles because it has no meaning independent of it's composition. Consider "to run". Whereas "running" is a gerund because of the suffix "-ing" and carries meaning, and therefore is the entity view of a process because it is a noun "to" carries none (understanding it's not a preposition in the context). "To run" confers the infinitive status on the verb.
If you're looking for a one-to-one correspondence between grammatical structure and metaphysical concepts, you're out of luck. 'And' clearly has semantic force, because we say "Don't give me any and's or but's" above and beyond it's logical semantics. So, as a lexeme it is polysemous, and is both a conjunction and a noun in a traditional grammar. And sometimes relations are indicated with punctuation because there is no phonetic basis for the relation as in the use of apposition "My uncles, Jay and Joe, are painters". In fact, some relations in grammar are endophoric or deictic giving no clue in punctuation, morpheme, or lexeme. In these cases semantics is contextual and left to the inference of the reader.

Relations relate various things to each other. In some contexts, it may be sufficient simply to track the elements being "related". This is a purely structural view on what a "relation" is.



x
y




James
Susan


Susan
Samantha


Susan
Albert



However, often, a relation is something that can be applied to things, but it has a meaning inherent to itself. In principle, the only way to define a relation inherently is via a system of composable predicates which terminates at certain relational primitives. For example:
friend(x, y) ↔ hangout(x, y) ∧ like(x, y) ∧ like(y, x)
Then this is not so complicated. We are already seeing how it is that relations can be related (!) to one another.
Relations are composable
If we think of relations as purely structural, it is somewhat trivial, yet unelucidating, to say that they can be composed. For these two relations:



x
y




James
Susan


Susan
Samantha


Susan
Albert



and



y
z




Susan
Golf


Samantha
Wrestling


Albert
Diving



We can join the relations together:



x
y
z




James
Susan
Golf


Susan
Samantha
Wrestling


Susan
Albert
Diving



It appears we have conjoined two separate relations, into one single relation relating three elements. But what does this 'relation' mean? Even if we try to surmise that the first table represented "is friends with", and the second table "likes this sport", when we put them together, we have to re-interpret and re-analyze what the combined relation from x to z represents. "Has a friend who likes this sport"?
Possibly. But arguably, this shows us that the 'structural' idea of a relation is really just misleading. When relations draw from real-world scenarios, there is often some "background information" for why those elements 'relate' in that way. Therefore, the common mathematical definition of a relation as "a subset of a product" is not adequate, in our scenario. That is just the syntactic character of relations. Actually, every relation must also be defined in terms of semantic primitives.
Relational algebra
The idea that "relations" are not concepts that emerge via the composition of entities (i.e., that "greater than or equal to" is identifiable with a set {(1, 0), (1, 1), (4, 0), (300, 101), ...} leads us to the idea that relations are defined in relation to each other. This means that, just as we composed entities together into tuples of entities, we can compose relations as tuples of relations, as a way of expressing "a relation that is the combination of these relations."
This allows us to treat relations in an elementary algebraic way, as the mere adposition of symbols. We can write the relation R, which is the "composition" of relations a, b, and c, as (a, b, c), or even abc, if we like.
We need to ensure we can do this soundly. For example, let's say "A friend is someone who you hang out with, and who you have a mutual liking with." All of these are binary relations. Syntactically, we can always combine relations of the same arity. For example:
Consider someone who:

is friendly
is happy
is rich
is healthy

If we assume that these either are semantic primitives, or that they decompose into semantic primitives (i.e., each is the composition of some primitives), it is arguably always semantically sound to further combine such semantic primitives (unless we impose further axiomatic rules regarding which predicates can not be related in certain ways; for example, we could add the axiom tall(x) ↔ ¬ short(x)). In other words, a collection of semantic primitives generates a whole world of potential compositional meaning.
What happens when we try to combine predicates of different arities? We realize that our language of "combination" is not specific enough. When we "composed" n relations of arity I, we were actually assuming that the entity x in question was all of those things (happy and friendly and rich and ...).
This makes the idea of combining two predicates of different arity somewhat clearer - to combine tall and is friends with, we cannot merge these into a "single predicate", but we can represent their combination with a logical connective, such as tall ∧ friends. It is simply an unavoidable fact that when we supply arguments to these predicates, we have to choose which argument goes where. Syntactically, it is possible to assign a different variable to every "argument position" in this predicate: tall(x) ∧ friends(y, z). Now we have a predicate that can be coherently interpreted: a set of 3 people, one of whom is tall, and the second being friends with the third. We could also have chosen to allocate the same variable to multiple arguments, such as:

tall(x) ∧ friend(x, y)
tall(y) ∧ friend(x, x)
or even tall(x) ∧ friend(x, x)

(As an exercise, state aloud those formulae and think about what the meaning of such a predicate is.) However, to keep things simple, we can actually treat such predicates as the predicate with distinct variables, plus a statement of equality. That would make them:

tall(x) ∧ friend(y, z) ∧ x = y
tall(x) ∧ friend(y, z) ∧ y = z
(try to write the last one yourself, as an exercise)

At this point, we have seen the basic elements of a system of composable relations. We can include more logical connectives, like ∨, ¬, ←, ↔, ∃, and ∀, if we want to be able to express more things.
However, what we have basically just built up is the standard presentation of first-order logic: predicates which can be combined with logical connectives, more or less. Therefore, I believe that first-order logic already has this property of being able to define relations "extensionally", as I asked in the question.
There is very much more to think about, from here, but this is a good starting point.
